# Mobile user bandwidth based content quality

Tags: php, apache, bandwidth

I'd like to display a video for users with high bandwidth and a static image for those with low bandwidth. I could just show images to all mobile web users.

I have found a mobile detection class [PHP Mobile Detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/).

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really possible with HTML/CSS/JS. You could download a test file with Javascript and measure the time, but this is bandwith wasting in my eyes. 
The only easy mechanism available that comes to mind is Flash, which has an inbuilt function for this (although I don't know how it actually works).

As a tip, I'd recomment showing the static imgage to all users at first with a neat little button where you can change to the video (I myself -and many others- prefer this even though I have a very good connection).

Comment: Even downloading a test file won't always work: if the user is already using most of his/her bandwith for something else, your test script may detect a low bandwidth, while a few seconds later the user is no longer using his/her bandwith at all.

Comment: this is of course true, another reason to not rely on such methods